# How to make an ajax request when a sub menu page is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have the following menu page with a sub page in **function.php**:

```
function data_menu() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Data',
        'Data',
        'administrator',
        'data',
        'data_content'
    );    
     add_submenu_page( 
        'Data' , 
        'Data', 
        'Data', 
        'manage_options', 
        'data',
        'data_content'
    );

}

add_action('admin_menu', 'data_menu');
```

I want to send an Ajax request to a PHP file, So I added javascript file to the admin dashboard in **function.php**:

```
function admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('my_custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js');
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_scripts');
```

Inside that file **script.js**:

```
window.onload = function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#toplevel_page_data ul.wp-submenu li:last-of-type', function() {
    console.log('menu clicked');
    $.post('file path', {}, 
        function(data){
            console.log(data)
        });
    });
};
```

Then when I click the menu, The sentence `menu clicked` is logged in the console.

I think the problem is that the Ajax request doesn't take enough time to be done, Before the page is opened.

The page URL becomes:

```
http://website.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=data
```

Is there is a way to make that Ajax request when the menu is clicked?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to send an ajax request before being routed to the page that you clicked on?

Comment: I want to send a request when that menu is clicked

Comment: Or that menu page is viewed by the admin

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier with an ajax request on the page you want to track views on instead of listening to menu button clicks?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // ajax request
});
```

Otherwise if you really want to post a request on menu click you have to intercept the menu click so it makes the request before routing. Something like:

```
$('.menu-link').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // otherwise, it won't wait for the ajax response
    $link = $(this); // because '$(this)' will be out of scope in your callback

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/url-to-post-to',
        data: mydata,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        error: function (err) {
            alert("error - " + err);
        },
        success: function () {
            window.location.href = $link.attr('href');
        }
    });
});
```

credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16563830/4820395